# ТрЕнеры или тренерА?

Tags: орфоэпия, множественное-число

В последнее время заметил, что многие (если не все) спортсмены говорят **тренерА**, а не **трЕнеры**. Это профессиональный жаргон? В каких-нибудь словарях есть **тренерА** с пометкой *разговорное*?

Comment: И ещё говорят *на первом, втором, третьем кругУ.* Но мне это не нравится, я стараюсь говорить "на круге".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из словарей:

1) Аванесов, 1987 год: тренеры, тренерА ― **неправильно!**

2) Резниченко, 2010 год: тренерА ― **только в профессиональной речи.**

3) Введенская (для работников радио и телевидения), 2012 год: тренерА ― **просторечное.**

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla!

Comment: в последние время такой простор для так называемой профессиональной речи! Хочешь - вот тебе дОбыча нефтИ, если ты нефтяник, говори на здоровье, никто не осудит. Я, признаться, источаю сарказм.